# How do I color a cell conditional on a factor and the current date in Excel?

Tags: date, colors, conditional-statements, formula

I have two columns. I want to color one column, conditional on the other and the current date.

For example: If the date in column A is more than one year ago, and the interval in column B is yearly, then I want to color that particular cell (i.e., cell A3)

[image: screenshot with example of result]

I can't solve this problem with the regular options in Excel, and probably need a formula. I tried to solve it using this logic (pseudo code, since I didnt get it to work)

=IF($B2="Yearly" AND <=ABS(NOW()-365,25); "color cell"; do nothing))

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with a single conditional rule

```
=OR(AND($L4 = "Monthly"; $K4 < ABS(NOW()-(365,25/12)));AND($L4 = "Quarterly"; 
$K4 < ABS(NOW()-(365,25/4)));AND($L4 = "Twice a year"; $K4 < ABS(NOW()- 
(365,25/2)));NOW($L4 = "Yearly"; $K4 < ABS(NOW()-(365,25))))
```

This returns true or false, so it can be used in the conditional formatting menu in Excel. I edited my answer, because my last answer caused an invalidation of this formatting when sorting the data. This one does not.